# The left half-open topology and the standard topology have a nice map between their open sets. Is there a name for this relationship?

Tags: general-topology

I'm pretty sure that the left half-open topology and the standard topology on the reals are not homeomorphic.

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/681451) which says that the half-open topology is not second-countable. $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, however, is second-countable. So, they're not homeomorphic.

However, there is a very natural map that translates **open sets** back and forth between these two.

Let's call the left half-open topology $\tau^½$ (generated by intervals of the form $(a, b]$) and $\tau^R$ the standard topology on the reals.

Let $i(\tau^A) : 2^X \to \tau$ be the interior operator of the topology $\tau^A$.

$\varphi : \tau^{½} \times \tau^R \to 2$ is a 2-place relation that is a function in both directions.

$$ \varphi(u, a) \stackrel{\text{def $\varphi$}}{\iff} i(\tau^R, u) = a $$

$\varphi^{\to}$ is only ever removing a point (in each open component in an open set, I'm not sure what you call it) and $\varphi^{\leftarrow}$ is only ever adding one.

So this map seems to preserve arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

It seems to preserve a lot of information about the relationships between open sets ... although not everything because the presence or absence of a countable basis is a fact about open sets.

Is there a name for this relationship?

Comment: What's $\varphi^{\leftarrow}(A)$ when $A = (0,1)\cup (1,2)$?

Comment: Right, good point, you get $(0, 2]$ ... it merged the two parts together.

Comment: Well $\Bbb R$ in the left-half open topology is submetrisable (it has a coarser metric topology $\tau^R$) and is a GO-space wrt $\le$ (generalised ordered space) whereas $\tau^R$ is an ordered space (same order). The order topology is coarser but all basic open sets can be chosen order-convex. Those are the well-known relationships between these topologies. Often a motivating example for all sorts of generalisations.